# Programming moves of the Knight in Chess with C

Tags: c, chess

Hi assignment is basicly putting K to the entered value of the Knight then putting X to the rest of the board. Then for each move that Knight can do we put number then we increase the number for example like this:

```
X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X
X X X 1 X 2 X X
X X 4 X X X 3 X
X X X X K X X X
X X 5 X X X 6 X
X X X 7 X 8 X X
X X X X X X X X
```

My Code is down below but when i run it i get the output as this:
42108284210828421082842108284210828421082842108284210828
42108284210828421082842108284210828421082842108284210828
42108284210828421082814210828242108284210828
42108284210828342108284210828421082844210828
42108284210828421082842108284210825421082842108284210828
42108284210828542108284210828421082864210828
42108284210828421082874210828842108284210828
42108284210828421082842108284210828421082842108284210828

So can you help me fix my code. Since i am a newbie my if else conditions are pretty lame so i could really apperiacte it if you could also help me putting simplier conditions inside the brickets.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void boardDefine();
void boardDraw();

int main()

{
    char board[8][8];
    int i,j,row,column;
    int nextMove;

    printf("Please enter the position of the Knight on the board\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&column);
    if(row<1||row>9||column<1||column>9)
    {
        printf("You must enter a value greater than zero");
    }

    boardDefine(board[8][8],i,j,row,column,nextMove);
    boardDraw(board[8][8],i,j);


    return 0;
}

void boardDefine(char board[8][8],int i, int j,int row,int column,int nextMove)
{
    nextMove=1;
    for( j=1;j<=8;j++)
    {
             for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {

            if(i==row&&j==column)
            {
                board[i][j]="K ";//Places the Knight to the position that entered by user
            }
            /*From here we are basicly showing where the Knight can move from its current position
            for this we first check that if both row and column values are inside the board or not
            after the L move if not then we put the nextMove value at that adress of the array
            */
            else if(row-1<=8&&row-1>=0&&column+2<=8&&column+2>=0&&i==row-1&&j==column+2)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row-1<=8&&row-1>=0&&column-2<=8&&column-2>=0&&i==row-1&&j==column-2)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row+1<=8&&row+1>=0&&column+2<=8&&column+2>=0&&i==row+1&&j==column+2)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row+1<=8&&row+1>=0&&column-2<=8&&column-2>=0&&i==row+1&&j==column-2)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row-2<=8&&row-2>=0&&column+1<=8&&column+1>=0&&i==row-2&&j==column+1)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row-2<=8&&row-2>=0&&column-1<=8&&column-1>=0&&i==row-2&&j==column-1)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row+2<=8&&row+2>=0&&column-1<=8&&column-1>=0&&i==row+2&&j==column-1)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else if(row+2<=8&&row+2>=0&&column+1<=8&&column+1>=0&&i==row+2&&j==column+1)
            {
                board[i][j]='0'+ nextMove;
                nextMove++;
            }
            else
            {
                board[i][j]="X ";//Places X to the places where Knight cant move.
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

//Then we use this function to print
void boardDraw(char board[8][8],int i, int j)
{
    for( j=1;j<=8;j++)
    {
             for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
             {
                 printf("%c",board[i][j]);
             }
             printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you enable all compiler warnings?

Comment: Did you swap `3` and `4` in your example?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry im new at this site what did you mean by "3" and "4" ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya using codeblocks and i didnt enabled anything extra.

Comment: @onurcevik try the minimal changes I suggested in my answer and check if they work for you.

Comment: @onurcevik I mean line 4 in the printout should be `X X 3 X X X 4 X`, not `X X 4 X X X 3 X`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that is not much important. I just typed it with hand to Show what i mean. Basicly for every move that Knight can do we are going to put nextMove variable to that point then gonna increase it value to Show how many moves that Knight can do from its current position and where can it move.

Comment: Edited code by changing the type of board from int to char.

Comment: @onurcevik It is very important, because reproducing the output that you show is a lot harder than the one with `3` preceding `4`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i coded that part in the program right i typed that part with my hand thats why its like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are several issues with your code, I will try to address as many as I can that should get your code running -

First of all, since you want to store a single printable character, you should change your type of the array to `char` instead of `int`. You will then assign single characters to the array position. So when assigning K it will be `board[i][j] = 'k';` and x will be `board[i][j]='x';`

Since you have now changed your type to char you will have to change the printf call to

```
printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
```

Finally for assigning the single digit numbers you cant simply assign `nextMove`.
You will have to assign `'0' + nextMove`. This way you will get the ASCII equivalent of the number in the array.

Another mistake you have made is you have passed `board[8][8]` to the function. 
`board[8][8]` would just mean the single element in the array. If you want to pass the entire array you have to pass just `board`.

Finally you ran your loops from 1 to 8. when the array is declared as board[8][8]. Any array declared as arr[x] goes from 0 to (x-1) and not 1 to x.
So your loops should be changed to

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

and similarly for j.
Rest all can be optimized but should work fine for now.

Comment: this time the program stops working after it takes the row and column values from user then returns -1073741819. I basicly chaned int to char like u said. then added '0' + nextMove line for all else if statements.

Comment: Did you also change `row` and `column` to char by mistake?

Comment: No just the board variable.

Comment: http://ideone.com/lLt7r6 Check this. Got it working here. A few other changes

Comment: Thank you it Works now. But the new problem is at output it prints K as "ë" and prints X as"ï"  for example for row : 2 column 2: the output is ï1ï2ïïïï
3ïïï4ïïï
ïïëïïïïï
5ïïï6ïïï
ï7ï8ïïïï
ïïïïïïïï
ïïïïïïïï
ïïïïïïïï

Comment: That could be because of different encoding on our systems. What is your default language set to?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot the change "K" as 'K'. Its perfect now thnx for the help. I chosed ur reply as answer.

Comment: Great! Couple of major changes you need to be careful of - 1) You shouldn't pass board[8][8] to the functions but just board, board[8][8] would mean that single character in the array, board would mean the entire array. 2) the array declared as arr[8] goes from 0-7 and not 1-8. So I changed your loops too. Just making sure you registered those changes.

Comment: I will also edit these changes into the answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things in your code that are not doing what you think they're doing. Without giving you explicit code (since this looks like a school project), I'll give you some pointers on how to make what you have more functional.

1. **Initialize the board:** You already know the location of the knight, so you should store that on the board first. Your boardDefine function already iterates over every element in the board, so try storing whatever value you're using to represent 'X' there if that spot isn't the knight or a spot the knight can move into.
2. **Shrink your conditional statements:** Your if statements are much more complicated than they need to be. Store the location of the knight somewhere and check if (i, j) is a valid move by adding or subtracting 2 to I or j and then adding or subtracting 1 from the other like so:

   ```
   //The '10' can be whatever number you're using to represent the knight
   if(board[i+2][j+1] == 10) {
       board[i][j] == nextMove;
       nextMove++;
   }
   ```

   Also make sure the indices of your board are ALWAYS between 0 and 7 inclusive, not 1 and 8. Otherwise you'll end up with a runtime error stating your index is out of bounds. If i = 6 and your code executes `board[i+2][j]` anywhere, you'll end up with a runtime error since 8 > 7.
3. **Assign values to what you want to print:** Since you're representing your board with an int array, you should be storing only ints in the array for clarity and code functionality. Try representing the knight and the X with an int, and when you print the board make sure you print a K or X when that int is reached. Lastly, when you're printing the board, read the value of the board and then execute the printf with the letter or number the value in the board represents. You can do this with an if or switch every time you read a new value off the board. Otherwise you might print a value you aren't trying to print.

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I dont know exactly where ur problem is, but did u try switch statement? 
It keeps your code simple, for example:

switch(1) {

```
case 1 : cout << '1'; // prints "1"

         break;       // and exits the switch
case 2 : cout << '2';

         // without break it will show 2 and after it 3 until next break

 case 3: cout << '3';
```

}

Comment: The question is marked as C. Even though switch case is fine cout and << isn't. Also your answer is not related to OPs problem

Comment: i dont think it'll simplify much considering the problem is the long conditions inside the bricket. Also this is currently least important of my problems. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: But you can also exclude your long condition into a function which returns a  boolean value of the condition.
So you can name your function with what the conditions stands for to keep it easier to read.
At the end you can also put a whole if-condition and the sub-if condition into a function and debug this function first to reach your target.